# Best way to display images from Rails Asset Pipeline using AngularJS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, coffeescript, asset-pipeline

I'm working on a Rails app with an Angular-driven frontend. I want to include images from my Rails asset folders into a view that is shown only shown in certain contexts using an `ng-switch` directive. I tried a couple of solutions, like typing the file path of all other (Rails-served) images into the `src` of the `<img>` tag. I also tried adding an erb suffix to the coffeescript file holding the angular controller and then doing this:

```
$scope.logoSrc = '<%= asset_path("images/logo_grey.png") %>'
```

and using an `ng-src` directive in the image tag, but that yielded a 404.

Happy to post more of my code if it's helpful. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: your solution with asset_path should be good, what's the resulting js?

Comment: @zeantsoi No, not yet unfortunately.

Comment: @apneadiving the resulting JS is `return $scope.logoSrc = '/assets/images/logo_grey.png';`

Comment: how come the error is `(No route matches [GET] "/assets/lapel-l-logo-dark-grey.png")` ... not the same picture?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$scope.logoSrc = '<%= asset_path("logo_grey.png") %>'
```

According to the [section 2.3.3](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets) of the Rails Guides:

> If you add an erb extension to a JavaScript asset, making it something such as application.js.erb, then you can use the asset_path helper in your JavaScript code:

```
$('#logo').attr({
  src: "<%= asset_path('logo.png') %>"
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this still yields `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/lapel-l-logo-dark-grey.png")`